# Ubuntu 18.04 debconf shows prompt

Tags: ubuntu, bash, mysql

I am trying to install MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 automatically using bash script.
I was setup all variables which debconf prompt asking, but prompt is appear anyway.
What's wrong in my script?

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

MYSQL_APT_FILE_NAME="mysql_apt_repository_tmp.deb"

echo "Installing MySQL Community Server..."

wget "https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb" -O 
$MYSQL_APT_FILE_NAME &> /dev/null

if [ -z "$(ls | grep $MYSQL_APT_FILE_NAME)" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Unable to download MySQL APT repository file"
    exit 0
fi

echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/repo-distro select ubuntu | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/repo-codename select trusty | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-server select mysql-8.0 | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-tools select Enabled | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-preview select Disabled | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password mystrongpassword | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password mystrongpassword | debconf-set-selections

sudo dpkg -i $MYSQL_APT_FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.
I needed to remove `sudo` from this line

```
sudo dpkg -i $MYSQL_APT_FILE_NAME
```

and after that run whole script as sudo.